# Problems in switching to TypeScript in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to switch my React app Components to Typescript.

I installed TS package and created a `tsconfig.json` file, `react-app-env.d.ts` files. And I also changed the extension from .js to .tsx. But in one of components I have an error. For example: in `<div>`

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="panel">
    <h2>Вхід</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Type '{ children: Element[]; class: string; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLDivElement>'.   Property 'class' does not exist on type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)

Comment: it should be `className="main-div"` not `class`

Comment: It literally tells you what the problem is `Property 'class' does not exist`

Comment: But I have the same problem with label. <label for="remember-me" className="remember"> <span>Запам'ятати</span> <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"/></span> </label>

Comment: Use `htmlFor` instead `for` in JSX templates.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that certain HTML attributes are also reserved words in Javascript, so to avoid problems, JSX syntax uses slightly different attributes from pure HTML.

The main two you're having trouble with are:

- `class` is now `className`
- `for` is now `htmlFor`

So your question would be:

```
<div className="main-div">
    <div className="panel">
    <h2>Вхід</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the label you posted in a comment would be:

```
<label htmlFor="remember-me" className="remember">
    <span>Запам'ятати</span>
    <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"/></span> 
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</div>` and the property is not `class`, but `className`

Comment: Thank you. But I have the same problem with label. `<label for="remember-me" className="remember">
            <span>Запам'ятати</span> <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"/></span>
        </label>`

Answer (score 0):

yo!

change `class` to `className` !

```
<div className="main-div">
    <div className="panel">
       <h2>Вхід</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```